# Browser downloads jnlp on Java Web Start. How to prevent it?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

When I click on a link to "web start" my java application, browser downloads jnlp file which I should execute afterwards. Is there any way to force browser to execute jnlp right after the download completes, or event better, to make the whole process transparent, so user just confirms that he wants to launch the application? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you can do is [provide the correct MIME type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#223) which in a standard setup makes the browser automatically open the file with Java WebStart.

Apart from that you cannot control whether the file is opened or not. Most browsers even have an option which prevents automatically opening downloaded files.